# Books on network theory

Tags: transient, circuit-theory, books

I really want to know which books should I read to learn the subject- Network theory in electrical engineering.
I know there are some popular books out there in the market, but I will really appreciate if you tell me names of some good books that are not so popular.
Please give me some suggestions.
Popular or non popular, I would love to know the name of every book that are good to learn this subject.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Re: "every book". This is really a basic topic at **every** university that teaches electrical engineering; there will be thousands of books! Recommendations will furthermore be mostly based on opinions, and such questions are off-topic here! Also, I feel like someone here definitely already asked for basic introductions to circuit theory, so maybe search a little harder on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It Depends on personal opinion and on which level of detail you are willing to read.

So I will give you my personal opinion...

If you want to start from scratch that is if you want to start from....atom,charges,electric fields, electric field in conductors, voltage,current, voltage and current sources...then refer

1. Matters and interactions - Ruth Chabay and Sherwood
2. Physics classroom.com website
3. Introductory circuit analysis - Robert l Boylestad

If you are already familiar with basics and want to learn further concepts like network theorems, transients,phasers,power calculations etc...

1. Engineering circuit analysis -Hayt and kemmerly
2. Fundamentals of electric circuits - Alexander sadiku

If you want to build problem solving skills and realise practical aspects...

1. Electric circuits - James w Nilsson, Susan
2. Introduction to electric circuits - Richard C.Dora, James A. Svoboda

I personally like Alexander sadiku ...